# Reading from an INI file

Tags: vb.net, ini

I find it very easy to write to a INI file, but am having some trouble in retrieving the data from an already created INI file.

I am using this function:

```
    Public Declare Unicode Function GetPrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "GetPrivateProfileStringW" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
    ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal lpDefault As String, _
    ByVal lpReturnedString As String, ByVal nSize As Int32, _
    ByVal lpFileName As String) As Int32
```

If I have an INI file called 'c:\temp\test.ini', with the following data:

```
[testApp]
KeyName=keyValue
KeyName2=keyValue2
```

How can I retrieve the values of KeyName and KeyName2?

I have tried this code, with no success:

```
    Dim strData As String
    GetPrivateProfileString("testApp", "KeyName", "Nothing", strData, Len(strData), "c:\temp\test.ini")
    MsgBox(strData)
```

Comment: No errors, just an empty string. strData gets returned with no data inside it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going to the [Pinvoke.Net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetPrivateProfileString.html) Web site and modifying their example worked, their Function declaration is different.

**Modified Example**

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text
Module Module1
    Private Declare Auto Function GetPrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpAppName As String, _
            ByVal lpKeyName As String, _
            ByVal lpDefault As String, _
            ByVal lpReturnedString As StringBuilder, _
            ByVal nSize As Integer, _
            ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer

    Sub Main()

        Dim res As Integer
        Dim sb As StringBuilder

        sb = New StringBuilder(500)
        res = GetPrivateProfileString("testApp", "KeyName", "", sb, sb.Capacity, "c:\temp\test.ini")
        Console.WriteLine("GetPrivateProfileStrng returned : " & res.ToString())
        Console.WriteLine("KeyName is : " & sb.ToString())
        Console.ReadLine();

    End Sub
End Module
```