# How to use an external config .ini file in VB .Net?

Tags: vb.net, winsock, ini

I have program in VB.Net that uses Winsock. I want to make an external config in .ini file. The program works when I'm running it, but when I want to lister the port I get an error.

Here is the function that reads .ini file:

```
Public Function GetSettingItem(ByVal File As String, ByVal Identifier As String) As String
    Dim S As New IO.StreamReader(File) : Dim Result As String = ""
    Do While (S.Peek <> -1)
        Dim Line As String = S.ReadLine
        If Line.ToLower.StartsWith(Identifier.ToLower & ":") Then
            Result = Line.Substring(Identifier.Length + 2)
        End If
    Loop
    Return Result
End Function
```

This it the Winsock Listen Port:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    AxWinsock1.LocalPort = GetSettingItem("D:\MainConfig.ini", "port")
    AxWinsock1.Listen()
End Sub
```

Error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
```

Where is the problem? How to listen port in .ini files?

Comment: What do the contents of the file look like? What error are you receiving? What does `GetSettingItem("D:\MainConfig.ini", "port")` return?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading from an INI file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238898/reading-from-an-ini-file)

Comment: i make 2 program server and client ... and the client want to control the server ...